# How to delete a specific number of files from many folders?

Tags: python, python-os

Let's suppose that I have a set of folders. I each folder I have more than 1000 files, I need to count 1000 in each folder than delete the rest,
For example:

Folder1  contains 1234 numpy files, I want to keep 1000 and delete the 234 files.

I use  python, I display number of files per folder, but I can't keep only 1000 files and delete the rest.

```
import os
b=0
for b in range(256):
    path='path.../traces_classes_Byte_0/Class_Byte_Hypothesis_'+str(b)
    num_files = sum(os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, f)) for f in os.listdir(path))
    print('Number of files in Class_Byte_Hypothesis_'+str(b)+' is ' +str(num_files))
```

Could you help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import os
for b in range(256):
    files = []
    path='path.../traces_classes_Byte_0/Class_Byte_Hypothesis_'+str(b)
    files = [f for f in os.listdir(path) if os.isfile(os.path.join(path, f))]
    if len(files) > 1000:
        for f in files[1000:]:
            os.remove(os.path.join(path, f))
```

I believe this should do the trick.

Comment: I got this error:      files = os.path.join(path, f)) for f in os.listdir(path))
                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Sorry I was careless with the syntax. Was focussing on the logic. files = [f for f in os.listdir(mypath) if os.isfile(os.path.join(path, f))]

Comment: let me know if that works and I will update my answer aswell

Comment: thank yoi for you answers, but it gives this  error: OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'file002.npy'. This file exists already.

Comment: Just add a path join command in the remove function. I realise that in the updated code, the path wasn't joined when inserting it into the list, just being checked